# How to access UIApplication subclass functions

Tags: ios, swift, uiapplication

I have VC1 that is subclass of UIApplication

VC1

```
   class CustomUIApplication: UIApplication {
       override func sendEvent(_ event: UIEvent) {
            super.sendEvent(event)
       }
            
       func stopTimer() {
                   
       }
            
       func startTimer() {
                    
       }
   }
```

VC2

```
class MyVC: ViewController {
   // want to access start timer func here
}
```

Instance of CustomUIApplication will be in main.swift

```
UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
    NSStringFromClass(CustomUIApplication.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)
```

Any help would be appreciated and advance thanks.

Comment: Where’s the instance of your CustomUIApplication held?

Comment: I have main.swift as below UIApplicationMain(
    CommandLine.argc,
    CommandLine.unsafeArgv,
    NSStringFromClass(CustomUIApplication.self),
    NSStringFromClass(AppDelegate.self)
)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to docs:

> Every iOS app has exactly one instance of UIApplication (or, very
> rarely, a subclass of UIApplication). When an app is launched, the
> system calls the UIApplicationMain(*:*:*:*:) function; among its other
> tasks, this function creates a Singleton UIApplication object.
> Thereafter you access the object by calling the [shared](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplication/1622975-shared) class method.

So in MyVC you should be able to do `CustomUIApplication.shared.startTimer()`.

Said that, may I suggest you to consider having a separate class for handling start/stop time functionality, instead of having a subclass of UIApplication? You can make your own singleton for that and access it from wherever you need in a similar way.

**EDIT**: Of course, you have to define `static var shared: Self { UIApplication.shared as! Self }` first. (Per [@Sulthan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/669586/sulthan)'s comment)

Comment: Of course, you have to define `static var shared: Self { UIApplication.shared as! Self }` first.